# Load phtml content in custom viewhelper?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

In my main layout.phtml i've included a custom viewhelper. The viewhelper has lot of static html content and returns it to the layout.

Is there a way that the viewhelper loads this html content from an external phtml file?

Abstract example:

```
Layout:
<?php echo $this->viewHelperGiveMeHtml();  ?> //<div>Foobar</div>

ViewHelper:
class Zend_View_Helper_ViewHelperGiveMeHtml extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract{

    public function viewHelperGiveMeHtml(){
        return retrieveHtmlFromPhtml('foobar.phtml');  //how can i load an phtml? file
    }   
}

foobar.phtml:
<div>Foobar</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function viewHelperGiveMeHtml(){
    $this->view->render('foobar.phtml');
}
```

Brief explanation:

When you're calling view helper `$this->viewHelperGiveMeHtml();` inside view, `Zend_View` initialise given helper class and passes itself using `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract::setView` method.

Comment: you could also render as a partial() or partialLoop() if you need to pass variables to it.